# HTML5 tag to refer to a list item choice within accompanying text

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am creating reference material to help users complete an online form, and need to refer to the form's choices within the referencing text.

Taking the following form item:

```html
<select multiple name="animal">
  <option value="cats">Cats</option>
  <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
  <option value="fish">Fish</option>
</select>
```

The accompanying text may be something like:

> For lovers of felines, please select Cats.  Canine fans should choose
>   Dogs.

It was suggested that I use `<strong>` to highlight them, but semantically it's not great:

```html
For lovers of felines, please select <strong>Cats</strong>.  Canine fans should choose <strong>Dogs</strong>.
```

Which HTML(5) tag should be used to highlight the item choices "cat" and "dog" in the text?  I've been through the ones at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_var.asp) and [found](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_var.asp) `<var>` which seems appropriate, but is there a *correct* semantic approach?

```html
For lovers of felines, please select <var>Cats</var>.  Canine fans should choose <var>Dogs</var>.
```

Comment: Have you considered span?

Comment: I've considered all sorts, including `<span>` and `<q>`, but need advice on the semantics rather than visuals.  I know CSS will easily let me pretty things up once the HTML is written

Comment: I would say `samp` or `var` (in that order) would be more suitable in your context. [From W3C `samp`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/text-level-semantics.html#the-samp-element) -- *represents (sample) output from a program or computing system* -- which in your case is that you are highlighting a recommended output of `select`.

Comment: [From W3C `var`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/text-level-semantics.html#the-var-element) -- *represents a variable. This could be an actual variable in a mathematical expression or programming context, an identifier representing a constant, a symbol identifying a physical quantity, a function parameter, or just be a term used as a placeholder in prose* -- which in your case may represent the selection choice parameter. However, I would lean towards `samp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you could simply use quotation marks:

```html
<p>For lovers of felines, please select "Cats". Canine fans should choose "Dogs".</p>
```

But if you want to use markup here, you could use [`kbd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) together with [`samp`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-samp-element):

> When the `kbd` element *contains* a `samp` element, it represents input based on system output, for example invoking a menu item.

So it would look like this:

```html
<p>For lovers of felines, please select <kbd><samp>Cats</samp></kbd>. Canine fans should choose <kbd><samp>Dogs</samp></kbd>.</p>
```

(Unless you make sure that the visual styling conveys this, also when printing the document or when color cannot be perceived etc., you may want to use quotation marks in addition.)

Comment: +1 for quotes and a facepalm for completely bipassing an obvious choice in my reading today...(!)  `<kbd><samp>` seems to be the intended way with regards to the specs, which is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The W3C describes `var` like this:

> The  element represents a variable. ref: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/var

MDN indicates `var`:

> represents a variable in a mathematical expression or a programming context. 
>   ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/var

I think applying emphasis fits your bill, and either `em` (for emphasis) or `strong` (for strong emphasis) would work for that purpose. Let me know if I haven't entirely understood what you are after.

Comment: Thank you.  I did wonder if `<em>` is suited slightly toward visuals rather than semantics for this (IMHO), but I agree that `<var>` is probably not right for this use (I did consider `<em>` when looking at `<strong>`.

Comment: @EvilDr There is indeed default styling that is applied to `<em>` - italicizing - but many elements get some sort of default styling (e.g. h1-h6). That doesn't mean they are "visual"  elements. As a bit of history, `<em>` and `<strong>` have tended to replace the visual `<i>` and `<b>` elements as they have more semantic meaning. Now having said that, HTML5 redefines what `<i>` and `<b>` actually mean semantically - http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags. Personally, if I am trying to empashize, i stick with `<em>` and `<strong>`.